# BUILD FAILED Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease', I can't make apk with flutter, the build takes too much time and then fails

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I am trying to build an apk but it fails, Everything was working fine few days ago, I tried everything that i could possibly find (i am a beginner though). I know it has something to do with Gradle, I installed openJDK 8 for it (it was working fine with JDk 14 few days ago)

I cant even run it on devices. I tried flutter clean and all

```
E:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color build apk
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                        


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


* What went wrong:

A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.

   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50.

     Required by:

         project :

      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50.

         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.

            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.

               > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.24.46] failed: Connection timed out: connect

      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.

            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.
               > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/54.148.239.199, jcenter.bintray.com/35.161.162.245, jcenter.bintray.com/52.41.115.189, jcenter.bintray.com/52.88.32.158] failed: Connection timed out: connect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5m 50s

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          352.4s (!)
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1
```

flutter doctor -v result

```
    [√] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.19.0-4.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.19.0-4.1.pre at E:\flutter
    • Framework revision f994b76974 (11 days ago), 2020-06-09 15:53:13 -0700
    • Engine revision 9a28c3bcf4
    • Dart version 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-14.1.beta)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: E:\New folder (2)\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at E:\New folder (2)
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.8052
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[!] VS Code (version 1.45.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    X Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Web Server • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
    • Chrome     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 83.0.4103.106

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

And I should also mention I also have problem in running "gralew build" it also shows an error

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: so sorry if it violates anything, its just that i  was in middle of my project but it crashed, and i want to finish it asap

Comment: That material is now removed. Remember your audience are volunteers, so it is (obviously) impolite to hurry them. Readers tend to answer questions selectively, and when they do, it is at their leisure.